# Is there a way to know that the makefile is running with -j (parallel execution)

Tags: makefile, parallel-processing, gnu-make

The `-j` option of GNU Make is handy although you have to be careful about your dependencies. In my environment it has sped up build and test times 5-6 times. But I want to run my tests with coverage and this creates a problem since the `gcov` instrumentation does not handle concurrency well, basically trying to write to the same `.gcda` file simultaneously.

I've figured out how to steer coverage information into separate directories for each test, which works. However this incurs the penalty of post-processing all coverage information.

So I'm looking for a way to know if `-j` has been used in the invocation, to be able to automatically avoid the extra processing if it is not necessary. Is that possible?

Comment: By default you should be able to access parameters used to call `make` throug `MAKEFLAGS` which is there essentially to know how `make` has been invoked and to allow propagating them into sub-make process(es).

Comment: Gaah, of course! Thanks. Make that an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default you should be able to access parameters used to call `make` through [`MAKEFLAGS`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Options_002fRecursion.html) which is setup automatically and is there essentially to know how make has been invoked and to allow propagating them into sub-make process(es).

Comment: Note that the value of `MAKEFLAGS` is _not_ available to `ifeq`-style expressions, e.g. 
`ifeq (,$findstring(j,$(MAKEFLAGS))
PARALLEL=true
endif`